# convert csv data to DataTable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, import, multidimensional-array, datatable

I am trying to import a large array of integers stored as a csv file into a VB.Net DataTable called `BeamMap`. The .csv file consists only of integers, with a delimiter of `,`, no quotes around the data (ie., `1,3,-2,44,1`), and an end of line character of line feed and carriage return. All I want to do is get each integer into a DataTable cell with the appropriate rows and columns (there are the same number of columns for each row) and be able to reference it later on in my code. I really don't want anything more than absolutely necessary in the code (no titles, captions, headings, etc.), and I need it to be fairly efficient (the csv array is approx. ~1000 x ~1000).

Thanks!

Comment: @AVD: How? This would probably be a good thing to put as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple approach which requires a strict format (as you've mentioned):

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
Dim tbl = New DataTable
Dim colCount = lines.First.Split(","c).Length
For i As Int32 = 1 To colCount
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_" & i, GetType(Int32)))
Next
For Each line In lines
    Dim objFields = From field In line.Split(","c)
                 Select CType(Int32.Parse(field), Object)
    Dim newRow = tbl.Rows.Add()
    newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
Next
```

Comment: What is the `c` after the delimiter for in line three? Also, would I make this a function or a sub?

Comment: @matt: Yes, it's a char literal, the same as `'c'` in C#. I don't understand your other question. It depends on your requirements if that belongs into a function or a sub. It simply creates a DataTable from a csv file,     no more, no less. You can return it or do whatever you need to do with it.

Answer (score 17):

Use `OleDb` provider to read CSV and pouplate the `DataTable`.

```
 Dim folder = "c:\location\of\csv\files\"
 Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [nos.csv]", CnStr)
       Adp.Fill(dt)
 End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the file from a mapped drive and putting the retrieved data in a dataset:

```
Dim folder = "Z:\"
Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"

Dim dssample As New DataSet
Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [samplecsv.csv]", CnStr)
    Adp.Fill(dssample)
End Using

If dssample.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    'some code here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to include the

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

And if you wish to link to a DataGridView (after read):

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource
bs.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```