# Find average of a specific number of rows/columns in VB.Net Datatable and store to array

Tags: database, vb.net, algorithm, math, noise-reduction

I am trying to program a noise reduction algorithm that works with a set of datapoints in a VB.NET DataTable after being helped with [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118678/convert-csv-data-to-datatable-in-vb-net). Basically, I want to take two integers, a coordinate value (`yCoord` for example) and a threshold smoothing value (`NoiseThresh`), and take the average of the values in the range of `(yCoord - NoiseThresh, yCoord + NoiseThresh)` and store that number into an array. I'd repeat that process for each column (in this example) and end up with a one-dimensional array of average values. My questions are:

1) Did anything I just say make any sense ;), and
2) Can anyone help me with the code? I've got very little experience working with databases.

Thanks!

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
//My data (pretend it's a database)
1  4  4  9  2  //yCoord would equal 5
6  3  8  12 3  //yCoord = 4
8  3 -2  2  0  //yCoord = 3
9 17  3  7  5  //yCoord = 2
4  1  0  9  7  //yCoord = 1

//In this example, my yCoord will equal 3 and NoiseThresh = 1

//For the first column
    Array(column1) = //average of the set of numbers centered at yCoord = 3 _
//(in this case 8) and the NoiseThresh=1 number on either side (here 6 & 9)
//For the second column
    Array(column2) = //average of the numbers 3,3,17 for example
    //etc., etc.,
```

This would be performed on a large data set (typical numbers would be yCoord=500, NoiseThresh = 50, Array length = 1092) so there is no possibility of manually entering the numbers.

I hope this helps clarify my question!

P.S.: yes, I know that // isn't a VB.NET comment.

Comment: This question targets an in-memory `DataTable`, so your note that you have only little experences  with databases is pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Not really... All I'm saying is that I'd like any code that's posted to come with an explanation or comments.

Comment: What i wanted to say is, do this all in database might be a better approach, all the more if this is a web-application with multiple users. You're loading all into memory what is not very scalable. And answers with a DataTable don't help you understanding SQL.

Comment: The range part is still unclear. What does `xCord/yCord/NoiseThreas` mean referred to the DataTable? Is `xCord` a column-index, `yCord` a row-position and `NoiseThreas` the range?

Comment: `xCoord`/`yCoord` refers to the column/row that the that is the centerpoint for the noise reduction algorithm, respectively. `NoiseThresh` is the number of data points to the left and right of xCoord to find the average of, or the number of data points above and below yCoord to find the average of. I want to repeat this averaging function for each datapoint in the column specified by xCoord as well as the datapoints in the row specified in yCoord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that i've yet not understood the range part (NoiseThresh etc.), but this is a start:

```
Dim averages = (From col In tbl.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
               Select tbl.AsEnumerable().
                      Average(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)(col.ColumnName))).
               ToArray()
```

It calculates every average of each column in the `DataTable` and creates a `Double()` from the result (average can result in decimal places even if used on integers).

**Edit**: With your example i've now understood the range part. So basically `yCord` is the row-index(+1) and `noiseThreas` is the row-range (+/- n rows).

Then this gives you the correct result(made some code comments):

```
Dim yCord = 2 ' the row index(-1 since indices are 0-based) '
Dim noiseThresh = 1 ' +/- row '
' reverse all rows since your sample begins with index=5 and ends with index=1 '
Dim AVGs As Double() = (
    From colIndex In Enumerable.Range(0, tbl.Columns.Count)
    Select tbl.AsEnumerable().Reverse().
    Where(Function(r, index) index >= yCord - noiseThresh _
                     AndAlso index <= yCord + noiseThresh).
    Average(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)(colIndex))).ToArray()
```

The most important part of this this `LINQ` query is the `Where`. It applies your range on the `IEnumerable(of DataRow)`. Then i'm calculating the average of these rows for every column. The last step is materializing the query to a `Double()`.

Result:

```
    (0) 7.666666666666667   Double  => (6+8+9)/3
    (1) 7.666666666666667   Double  => (3+3+17)/3
    (2) 3.0                 Double  => (8-2+3)/3
    (3) 7.0                 Double  => (12+2+7)/3
    (4) 2.6666666666666665  Double  => (3+0+5)/3
```

**Edit2**:

> One last thing. I assume that to do the same for the other axis I just
>   switch x & y and row & column?

It's not that simple. But have a look yourself:

```
Dim noiseThresh = 1 ' +/- column '
Dim xCord = 2 ' the column index(-1 since indices are 0-based) '
' assuming that your x-cords now start with index=0 and ends with tbl.Column.Count-1 '
Dim AVGs As Double() = (
    From rowIndex In Enumerable.Range(0, tbl.Rows.Count)
    Select tbl.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().
    Where(Function(c, colIndex) colIndex >= xCord - noiseThresh _
                        AndAlso colIndex <= xCord + noiseThresh).
    Average(Function(c) tbl.Rows(rowIndex).Field(Of Int32)(c.Ordinal))).ToArray()
```

Result:

```
    (0) 5.666666666666667   Double  => (4+4+9)/3
    (1) 7.666666666666667   Double  => (3+8+12)/3
    (2) 1.0                 Double  => (3-2+2)/3
    (3) 9.0                 Double  => (17+3+7)/3
    (4) 3.3333333333333335  Double  => (1+0+9)/3
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a bit on how I would set this up in my situation?

Comment: @Matt: I've edited my answer, if you have questions, ask. Added also the result and the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Now do I need to loop this for every average I want to get? In my example, is this just column one, or is this an array of the averages for each column?

Comment: One last thing. I assume that to do the same for the other axis I just switch x & y and row & column?

Comment: @Matt: Edited again to provide the x-axis version.

Comment: I didn't want to put [my next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137009/add-data-points-from-double-array-to-existing-vb-net-chart-series) as part of this one, because it was already a pretty long question. However, it is directly connected. Would you be willing to take a look?

Comment: @Matt: I would, but i'm afraid that i'm running out of time. I have also no experiences with the [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456391) class. You should also provide your code in your question and/or links to the chart you're using to make it more clear.