# Add data points from Double() array to existing VB.NET chart series

Tags: vb.net, arrays, plot, double

I have an array of type `Double()` (1 x *n*) that I am trying to quickly plot on a graph I've already set up. The only thing I want/need to do is take my array and store it as data points (y-axis values) in the series I already have. What's the best way to do this? Also, will the data points that are plotted change as my array changes, and if not, how would I replot those new points and get rid of the old points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the points should be as simple as

```
Chart1.Series("Default").Points.Add(arrayName)
```

As for it being auto-updated when you change the array, I believe if you just add the points, you are going to have an issue like pee in a swimming pool (once they are in there, you can't get them out).  So, you add an array with 3 items, then add a double to the array, then the add to the chart again, you now incorrectly have 7 points.  However, you can databind the array to the series, like so.

```
Chart1.Series("Default").Points.DataBindXY(xStrings, xDoubles)
```

In this case, if the array changes, the chart should change as well.