# Data bind an array to a chart series in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, data-binding, charts

How do you data bind a Series to an array of numbers?

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137009/add-data-points-from-double-array-to-existing-vb-net-chart-series) I would've hoped it'd be that easy, but it's not.

My basic code example:

```
dim xarray = {2, 30, 40, 50}
dim yarray = {1, 20, 40, 10}

dim newSeries = new DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
newSeries.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

newSeries.points.DataBindXY(xarray, yarray)

xarray = {1,2,3,4}
myChart.series.add(newSeries)
```

Throwing this into a debugger and stepping through you see the two arrays are successfully apart of the series. After the 6th line of code, going back to see if the series was updated shows it wasn't. In my code I have to go digging for these two arrays which reside in a BindingList, but the concept is the same since I'm still working with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`vb.net` is a line by line programming language. Sadly, your

```
newSeries.points.DataBindXY(xarray, yarray)
```

actually codes:

```
newSeries.points.DataBindXY({2, 30, 40, 50} , {1, 20, 40, 10}).
```

So, modifying later on `xarray` won't modify the chart. Everytime you modify `xarray`or `yarray`, you have the call `DatabindXY`.

So, to work, it would have to be :

```
dim xarray = {2, 30, 40, 50}
dim yarray = {1, 20, 40, 10}

dim newSeries = new DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
newSeries.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

newSeries.points.DataBindXY(xarray, yarray)

xarray = {1,2,3,4}
newSeries.points.DataBindXY(xarray, yarray)

myChart.series.add(newSeries)
```