# Adding array to Chart only plots first value

Tags: vb.net

VB.net - How come only one point is plotted?

```
Dim ReceivedValue As String ="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"
Dim myArray = Array.ConvertAll(ReceivedValue.Split(","c), AddressOf Convert.ToDouble)
Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(myArray)
```

PS. I got the plot array idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137009/add-data-points-from-double-array-to-existing-vb-net-chart-series)

Comment: A point is two values (X and Y). This is an array of single values (just X?). How do you want this graphed? Do you want them paired up? Do you have set value for X or Y? Do you want the X or Y value to be the index in the array?

Comment: Good question, the x doesn't matter at this point. It is reference waveform and no labels or numbers are even shown.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same results as you - one point on the chart. Upon inspecting the chart's Points object, it looks like this:

[image]

Showing an array with one X=0, and an array of all the Ys.

If you do it in a loop like this, it works

```
For Each point In myArray
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(point)
Next
```

Now there is an actual series of points

[image]

[image]

I'm going to add what I think is more correct, because this results in actual x, y pairs with real x values (you can make them whatever you want)

```
For i = 0 To myArray.Count - 1
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(New DataPoint(i, myArray(i)))
Next
```

Comment: Ok thank you. That makes sense. I think that solution is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand, all the Y values were plotting top of the same X position.

Comment: Yes, even though when inspecting the Points object when added in a loop, all the Y values also have X = 0, the chart is able to chart it for some reason.