# Trying to convert Excel file into a Datatable and afterwards into a List of objects

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert a Excel-File into a DataTable and then into a List of Objects. My problem is, that the datatable is always empty, here is what i have tried:

- First build the connection String

  ```
   Public Function BuildConnectionString(excelPath As String) As String
   If excelPath.Substring(excelPath.LastIndexOf(".")).ToLower = ".xlsx" Then
       Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excelPath & ";Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
   Else
       Return "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & excelPath & ";Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
   End If
  ```

  End Function
- Convert Excel to Datatable (doesn't Work)

  ```
   Private Function ConvertCSVToDataTable(ByVal path As String) As DataTable
   Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
   Using con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
       Try
           con.ConnectionString = String.Format(BuildConnectionString(path))
           Using cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con)
               Using da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                   con.Open()
                   da.Fill(dt)
                   con.Close()
               End Using
           End Using
       Catch ex As Exception
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
       Finally
           If con IsNot Nothing AndAlso con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
               con.Close()
           End If
       End Try
   End Using

   Return dt
  ```

  End Function
- Convert DataTable to List of Objects

  ```
    Private Function ConvertDataTableToCSVListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACServiceExcel)) As List(Of ISAACServiceExcel)

   For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
       Dim AnzahlParse As Double
       Double.TryParse(row(Anzahl), AnzahlParse)
       Dim EinzelkostenParse As Double
       Double.TryParse(row(Einzelkosten), EinzelkostenParse)
       Dim TotalParse As Double
       Double.TryParse(row(Total), TotalParse)
       Dim ISAAC As New ISAACServiceExcel(row(Leistungscode).ToString, row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, AnzahlParse, row(Einheit).ToString, EinzelkostenParse, row(Summencode).ToString, row(AufPos).ToString, row(Komponente).ToString, row(Projektbeteiligter).ToString, row(Chefblattposition).ToString, TotalParse)
       lst.Add(ISAAC)
   Next

   Return lst
  ```

  End Function

You can also write code in C#, if thats easier for you. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that does this and is working fine.

```vbnet
Public Function loadExcelData(filename As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = connString(filename)

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Plan1$]"
            cn.Open()
            
            Try
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    Return dt
End Function
```

But, in my case, I'm importing XLSX and XLS files, for CSV you can probably use something for a plain text, as you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11119089/4081081).