# can you search through a csv in vb.net (winforms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv

im trying to search for dates in a csv that has a few fields per entry, and im really struggling to find out how i can do this.
Ive looked through google and some (even very old) forums, and i cant seem to find anything other than the info that vb.net has an inbuilt csv tool.
please excuse my ignorance, im very new to vb and just trying to figure it out :)
can anyone help? thankyou very much in advance

Comment: How about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files ?

Comment: Problems usually get easier if you split them into smaller problems. Try this: (a) Write an app that reads your CSV file and outputs, for example, the first column only. (b) Write an app that has a list of items and loops though those to find an item. (c) Combine the knowledge gained by (a) and (b) to solve your original problem. Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer i have been looking at that yes, but what would i use to search for a string from that csv?

Comment: @Heinzi that is very true, and a very good way of going about it thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to load your CSV file in-memory. You can load the CSV file into a DataTable ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable)) using the OleDb provider as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120351/1920035

The next step would be querying the data. The DataTable class provides the Select method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select)) that allows you to pass a filter expression. To filter by date values, you wrap the date literals in pound signs, e.g. `#2023-02-27#`.

The last step would be displaying the data, but since you did not provide enough information in your original post, I cannot help you with this one.

Here is putting it all together:

```vb
Private Function LoadCsv(path As String) As DataTable
    Dim folder = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
    Dim filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
    Dim connection = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={folder};Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim csv = New DataTable

    Using adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter($"select * from [{filename}]", connection)
        adapter.Fill(csv)
    End Using

    Return csv
End Function

Private Function FilterOnOrBeforeDate(csv As DataTable, column As String, value As DateTime) As DataRow()
    Return csv.Select($"{column} <= #{value}#")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

@David post a complete and fast way to search in csv : anyway this is a "manual" and slow method to understand basic reading and searching csv file : (note that separator character inside fields content will cause random behavior )

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class CSV
    Private Sub scanCSV()
        Dim sr As New StreamReader("d:\files\file.csv") 'useful method to read any strings file
        Dim lineNum As Integer
        sr.ReadLine() 'rem this line if your file has no header
        While Not sr.EndOfStream ' stop loop when file eof
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine() 'read entire line
            For Each str As String In line.Split(",") 'split cut line into separated parts - separator =","
                If IsDate(str) Then 'vb function to test if string is a valid date
                    'date found
                    MsgBox("date found in line N°" & lineNum & " date = " & str)
                End If
            Next
            lineNum += 1 'increment line number
        End While
 end sub
end class
```

Comment: thats super duper helpful thankyou, ill test this out tomorrow and mark it as the correct answer, thankyou so much